# Repeat the same filter avoiding the UNION ALL clause

Tags: questdb

I would like to filter my data within a time interval but in consecutive days for a determined amount of days.
I know I can achieve that using

```
select insert_datetime from table WHERE insert_datetime IN '2022-09-02T01:00:00;10m'
UNION ALL
select insert_datetime from table WHERE insert_datetime IN '2022-09-03T01:00:00;10m'
```

But is there another way to got the same result avoiding the `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that using the extra parameters for the `IN` clause.

```
select insert_datetime from table WHERE insert_datetime IN '2022-09-02T01:00:00;1m;1d;2'
```

Using this you are saying that you want your data to be filtered every day (`1d`) and do this for 2 times.
There's an issue to add it to the documentation [here](https://github.com/questdb/questdb.io/issues/1076)